# PHP - не срабатывает return после цикла for

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Делаю приложение на PHP используя фреймверк Laravel. Проблема в том, что после цикла for не срабатывает return, если закомментировать все тело цикла, то return работает корректно возвращая значения. Вот сам цикл for

```
for ($i=0; $i<$profilesCount; $i++) {
    $proxy = Proxy::all()->where('status', 0)->first();
    if (!$proxy) {
        $failedProxy++;
        continue;
    }
    $proxy->status = 0;
    $proxy->save();
    $proxy = $proxy->proxy;
    $task = new Task;
    $task->type = 'profile_preparation';
    $task->status = 0;
    $task->save();
    $profile = new Profile;
    $profileName = HRRS::readable_random_string();
    $profile->name = $profileName;
    $profile->proxy = $proxy;
    $profile->save();
    $expirationDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+' . $formData['preparationDaysCount'] . ' days'));
    $taskParameters = [
        'taskId' => $task->id,
        'profileId' => $profile->id,
        'profileName' => $profileName,
        'proxy' => $proxy,
        'expirationDate' => $expirationDate
    ];
    $task->parameters = json_encode($taskParameters, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $task->save();
}
```

И вот return, идет сразу после цикла:

```
return [
    'code' => 1,
    'message' => 'test text'
];
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: что значит не срабатывает? падает с ошибкой? просто игнорируется?

Comment: Немного не по теме, но...во-первых, делать `$proxy = Proxy::all()->where('status', 0)->first();` в цикле, т.е. запрос к БД, это оооочень плохая затея. По основному вопросу - сейчас отвечу.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, метод контроллера полностью.

Comment: `$profileName = HRRS::readable_random_string(); $profile->name = $profileName;` почему не просто `$profile->name = HRRS::readable_random_string();`?

Comment: `$task->parameters = json_encode($taskParameters, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` - тоже очень плохой подход. Везде, где вы будете изменять параметры таска, вам придется делать `json_encode`. Вместо этого, вы можете указать в свойстве `$casts` модели `Task`, что `parameters` - это массив: `protected $casts = ['parameters' => 'array']`. Тогда вам нужно будет просто передавать массив, а манипуляции с json'ом Eloquent будет делать сам.

Comment: Ошибок нет, просто игнорируется.

Comment: Полный код метода, к сожалению, не влезает в комментарий, но там до цикла ничего больше нет (2 переменных и все). И после цикла сразу этот return идет

Comment: А что будет, если попробовать сделать вот так: `return response()->json(*тут массив*)`?

Comment: Тоже не работает